# Is it possible to save an R script, with unique parameters used in the script, after it has run?

Tags: r, parameters, copy, save

I'm using R for some processes, and I was wondering if it was possible to save a copy of an Rscript with the parameters in the script after it has ran - instead of `args[1]`. This would let the user be able to open the saved Rscript in Rstudio after the script has ran, with their argument instead of `args[x]` for any alterations they might want to make to plots.

For example:

```
Rscript plot_script.r path/to/file

read.table(args[1])
```

Should be:

```
read.table("path/to/file")
```

In the saved output Rscript.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. This would be every problematic for other variable types. If you want to print the value out, then you should add something like `print(paste("path", args[1]))` explicitly to your code.

Comment: Not the same, but you can use R Markdown templates for this type of thing.